# Find out if Video.JS is using HTML5 or the Flash Player

Tags: jquery, video.js

I am using VIDEO.JS and i need to find out which player video.js is using for a Javascript function.. Example

```
var myPlayer = videojs("the_player_id");
if (myPlayer.currentTechnology() == "flash") {
    console.log("its using the flash player");
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the API for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the minified code the variable gets obfuscated, but in the unminified version you can use `myPlayer.techName`

Answer (score 0):

The property can still, however, be accessed in the minified code too. Instead it is:

```
myPlayer.xa
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. It changes with each version (My version is currently "Ta")