# How to detect the tech of a player object?

Tags: video.js

We need to take various actions based on the tech that a videojs player object ends up using, notably doing some things when it is flash and others when it is html5.

I can't find anything in the API docs or here (searched combinations of things like 'tech' and 'detect'), but wonder if I'm overlooking something?

I have a valid reference to the player object, so that's not an issue. I saw in the source some references to a 'tech' field or a 'techName' field, but they're not in the API docs and actually don't seem to have meaningful values on the player objects I'm getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out if Video.JS is using HTML5 or the Flash Player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827131/find-out-if-video-js-is-using-html5-or-the-flash-player)

Answer (score 0):

There's philosophical blockers as to why this isn't exposed, here's the issue discussion from the video.js developers, interesting reading - and interesting counter use-cases: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1234

Answer (score -1):

You can detect what tech is being used, but it depends on whether you have minifed or unminified versions of the video.js code.

Minified: `myPlayer.xa`
Unminified: `myPlayer.techName`

Not being documented, and having also been somewhat obfuscated (in the case of minified), relying on it will make your code vulnerable to future changes that may cause it to fail.

Comment: The minified one changes per version. On my current version it is "Ta"